# Notify producer to stop producing when consumer raise exception in the asyncio.Queue produce-consume flow

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

A mock produce-consume flow based on the `asyncio.Queue`:

```py
import asyncio


async def produce(q: asyncio.Queue, task):
    asyncio.create_task(q.put(task))
    print(f'Produced {task}')


async def consume(q: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        task = await q.get()
        if task > 2:
            print(f'Cannot consume {task}')
            raise ValueError(f'{task} too big')
        print(f'Consumed {task}')
        q.task_done()


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(queue)) for _ in range(2)]
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.create_task(produce(queue, i))
    await asyncio.wait([queue.join(), *consumers],
                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)


asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is:

```
Produced 0
Consumed 0
Produced 1
Consumed 1
Produced 2
Consumed 2
Produced 3
Cannot consume 3
Produced 4
Cannot consume 4
Produced 5
Produced 6
Produced 7
Produced 8
Produced 9
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<consume() done, defined at test.py:9> exception=ValueError('3 too big')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in consume
    raise ValueError(f'{task} too big')
ValueError: 3 too big
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<consume() done, defined at test.py:9> exception=ValueError('4 too big')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in consume
    raise ValueError(f'{task} too big')
ValueError: 4 too big
```

Is there a way to notify the producer to stop producing after exception raised from consumer(s)?
The code above uses multiple producers. **It is also acceptable if the "notification" mechanism can only work at the single producer mode.**

Comment: The queue allows a `maxsize` parameter and a `full()` method. You could have the producers stop when the queue is full.

Comment: @Mike67 Thanks, but first: what if I don't wanna initialize a queue with `maxsize`? second: even if a "maxsized" queue is `full()`, doesn't mean the producer should stop producing since the consumers may have not raised exception yet.

Comment: A typical producer would contain a `while` loop that obtains the elements from an external source and stuffs them into the queue. You should use `await q.put()`, not `asyncio.create_task` because the latter defeats the purpose of `put` being a coroutine (providing backpressure when the queue is full). You will probably also need to add an `await asyncio.sleep(0.01)` or equivalent to emulate a context switch which would occur naturally if the producer actually interacted with an external source.

Comment: As for your question, have you tried simply setting a global Boolean variable in case of consumer exception, and check it in the producer?

Comment: @user4815162342 IMHO, the `while` loop you mentioned is more like a single producer mode? If one uses multiple producers, I think that `while` loop shouldn't be inside in any single producer of the multiple producers?  
You're right about the `await q.put()`. I've set a queue with `maxsize=1` and the `asyncio.create_task` would break that limitation while `await q.put()` would not.

Comment: There is typically a loop in both the producer and the consumer, independently of how many of them are working in parallel. Of course, one-shot producers might make sense for your use case, but that's hard to confirm based on the code snippet provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)'s suggestion

> setting a global Boolean variable in case of consumer exception, and check it in the producer

```py
import asyncio

stop = False


async def single_produce(q: asyncio.Queue):
    global stop
    for task in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
        if stop:
            break
        await q.put(task)
        print(f'Produced {task}')


async def multi_produce(q: asyncio.Queue, task):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
    await q.put(task)
    print(f'Produced {task}')


async def consume(q: asyncio.Queue):
    global stop
    while True:
        task = await q.get()
        if task > 2:
            stop = True
            print(f'Cannot consume {task}')
            raise ValueError(f'{task} too big')
        print(f'Consumed {task}')
        q.task_done()


async def main(mode):
    global stop
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(queue)) for _ in range(2)]
    if mode == 'single':
        print('single producer')
        await asyncio.create_task(single_produce(queue))
    elif mode == 'multiple':
        print('multiple producers')
        for i in range(10):
            if stop:
                break
            await asyncio.create_task(multi_produce(queue, i))
    await asyncio.wait([queue.join(), *consumers],
                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)


asyncio.run(main('single'))
# asyncio.run(main('multiple'))
```